# USB web cam flickering on Ubuntu 16.04 running on VMWare 10.0.0 with a Windows 10 home edition host

Tags: windows-10, vmware, webcam, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-workstation

As the title reads: I have a Windows 10 Home edition host running an Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS on VMWare version 10.0.0.

I am developing an application which requires the use of a web cam, so I bought a Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 to serve my purpose, and that's where the problem began. The cam flickers when I connect it to Ubuntu:
[The flickering is dynamic, even when the cam is is at rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KbRu.png)

I have researched allot on the matter and I can't seem to find a working solution to my problem.

I'm doubting that VMWare is the source of the problem since I've tried connecting other cameras where 2 of them worked when I connected another cam to Ubuntu, but they even flickered, one of them was flickering only green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After allot of troubleshooting, it turned out to be a VMWare related problem. Upgraded VMWare to version 12.5.5 and that seemed to have fixed the problem in this particular situation.